# How to classify puppet nodes on the foreman into the hosts group based of a facter

Tags: puppet, host, foreman

Is there a way to classify puppet nodes on Foreman into a host group by facter. I know we can add the nodes manually  into the hosts group but is there a way that the nodes are assigned to a host group automatically based on their facter? for example those nodes match with osfamily Debian are added to the host group of Ubuntu and those one their osfamily match with Redhat are assigned to Centos group .

We have this on the Puppet Console by defining a rule when we create a node group. I'm interested to see if we can have this on the foreman

Answer (score 0):

Nodes can be classified dynamically just on the puppet enterprise . The puppet master that I was working on was puppet open source and this feature is not available on the Puppet open source: https://puppet.com/product/puppet-enterprise-and-open-source-puppet